# Modifying scikit-learn code locally

Tags: scikit-learn

I am a new python programmer and I just changed an original python file in model_selection folder in anaconda3

However, when I run the code it run the original version not the new one
Is there any code I can run to make these changes take a place

The full traceback:

Command "C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\...\scikit-learn\setup.py';f‌​=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users...\scikit-learn\ –

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend not to change the libraries but to extend the specific classes or methods to add the custom functionality and then use that.

Comment: Thank you very much .. could you please explain more how to do that ..

Comment: Please add the code you changed in the question, then we can try something.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably not change the code in anaconda folders.
If you want to make changes to scikit-learn code (for yourself), the best way is to:

1. Uninstall scikit-learn: `conda remove scikit-learn` or `pip uninstall scikit-learn`. You can check that it's correctly removed, with `pip list` and `conda list`.
2. Choose a directory where you want to have the scikit-learn files.
3. From this directory, download the code from github with git: `git clone git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`
4. Install it in an editable fashion with pip: `pip install --editable .`

Then any edit done on the code will be applied.
Note that if you edit Cython/C code (.pyx or .c files), you will have to recompile them before the changes take place, using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Comment: Thank you so much .. When I try to install it using the command in point 4 it displayed this message " Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found

Comment: I forgot to mention you have to be inside the scikit-learn directory, where you have a `setup.py` file.

Comment: Thanks.. I did that and I got the following message: "develop --no-deps" failed with error code 1 in c:\Users\..scikit-learn... Not sure if it installed correctly or not?

Comment: Command "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\...\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" develop --no-deps" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\...\scikit-learn\

Comment: Could you copy the full traceback on your original post?
I also forgot to mention that you need the `Cython` package to compile the code.

Comment: Is it possible to make a completely separate copy of sklearn, e.g., one untouched/original version in the anaconda or python folder and a separate, editable copy in the project folder?  I'm guessing this would require the editable version to have a different name than original.

Comment: I don't think you can install two python libraries with the same name. You can change the name of the editable version in `setup.py`, but it might not be straightforward for scikit-learn. You might also consider installing each version in a separate virtual environment.