# how to make sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor not take care of impurity decrease heuristic

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using RandomForestRegressor of sklearn to implement Random Forest Imputation. Sklearn allows us to set parameter `min_impurity_decrease` to specify the heuristic of split stopping criteria. For example, if `min_impurity_decrease = 0.0`, and if a node split results in a worse impurity, then the node will be made a leaf node.

The problem is that, I prefer Random Forest to be fully grown without early stopping or pruned. But `min_impurity_decrease` has to be set as a non-negative float. Is there any solution to this situation?

Intuitively, I have tried to set `min_impurity_decrease = float("-inf")`, which results in error message.

Comment: I am afraid that this is going to be hard to do. I am not sure it does make sense to do that though.

Comment: @TomDLT I think according to Breiman’s original paper, a tree of random forest is designed to fully grown without early stop or pruned. For random forest, even though a split might result in degenerating the impurity, I believe the overall algorithm prefers diversity at the end since voting takes care of it. But I will compare the pruned and unpruned random forest accuracy performance, if I can figure it out how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You apparently have to modify sklearn code. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46473838/4553309) on how to install sklearn in editable mode. Be sure to create new virtual environment so as to not mess up original sklearn files.

Good news is you don't have to change any Cython code. Go to file `sklearn/tree/tree.py`. A check for the value of `min_impurity_decrease` only seems to be present in `BaseDecisionTree` class. According to Github, in 306 line there is a code snippet:

```
if self.min_impurity_decrease < 0.:
        raise ValueError("min_impurity_decrease must be greater than "
                         "or equal to 0")
```

Simply delete this and reload the library. I couldn't test this solution, so let me know if you run into some problem.